# jQuery hover or JavaScript mouseout event for menu "sign in"

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I have site http://change.is for which I have a jQuery or JavaScript problem for the menu item "sign in".

When user hover the "sign in" then a jQuery function is called to show the upper header div. But now I have the problem in `mouseout` of upper header div "login-header" to hide the upper header div "login-header". It is not working.

As this upper div "login-header" contains another two divs "welcome-div" and "sing-in-all-forms" so `mouseout` event for main "login-header" is called.

Comment: I just deleted my answer after looking at your site. It's a UI flaw. fix it with a better UI, not with JavaScript. There is no user-intent detection so the header is really annoying.

Comment: So please let me know how to do this. An idea where to go for this.

Comment: what you have tried so far ? show some code

Comment: (Offtopic)... adobe flash player for playing videos? It's 2022.

Answer (score 0):

Make the "login-header" div big enough to house both the bar and the contents placed above it when "sign in" is clicked, so one doesn't "mouse out" when entering those.